# Win32: Reading WS_VSCROLL style from a combo box (or list box)

Tags: winapi, combobox, listbox, styles

I'm iterating through the controls in a dialog and I'm trying to determine if a combobox was created with the WS_VSCROLL style.

The style, obtained from `GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE)`, doesn't contain the WS_VSCROLL bit (0x200000), even when I know it was set on create.

---

Clarification:  I am looking to see if the ComboBox was *created* with the WS_VSCROLL style.  Calling GetWindowLong() (or using spy++) to get the style of the combo's *listbox* will include WS_VSCROLL *if* a scrollbar is needed to based on the current contents of the list.

I am trying to determine if the ComboBox was *created* with WS_VSCROLL, not if a scrollbar is *currently* visible.

Answer (score 2):

Then something removed the style. Styles don't just *dissapear* (AFAIK). What does Spy++ or [WinCheat](http://alinconstantin.dtdns.net/Download/WinCheat/Default.htm) tell you?

Also keep in mind comboboxes consist of more than one HWND. There's the outer control, a text box (if applicable), and a list box. You're probably more interested in the list box's style.

**EDIT:** Use [GetComboBoxInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775939(VS.85).aspx) to programmatically get the HWND of the list box.

Comment: They disappear if the implementation of the control removes it specifically. Could be that it does because the list is what requires that style rather than the parent window.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, +1

Comment: The combo (and list box) don't actually store WS_VSCROLL from create in the windows style.  The winproc updates WS_VSCROLL when the list is manipulated (add/remove/etc) so that it indicates if a vertical scrollbar is currently displayed